# What does 'computable in the limit from above' mean?

Tags: computability, terminology

$H(x)$ is the program size complexity of $x$ for some universal Turing machine $U$. $H$ is not computable, however $H$ is "*computable in the limit from above*".

From my notes:

> i.e the set $\{(x,n) \mid x \in B^*,n \geq 0, H(x) \leq n\}$ is computably enumerable.

Can someone tell me what this means? I understand the incomputability of $H$ but the term "limit from above" is confusing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicomputable_function)/[Scholarpedia](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Turing_machine#Semicomputable_functions),

> A partial function $f$ from the rational numbers to the real numbers is
>   **upper semicomputable** if it is defined by a rational-valued partial
>   computable function $\phi(x,k)$ with $x$ a rational number and $k$ a
>   nonnegative integer such that $\phi(x,k+1)≤ϕ(x,k)$ for every $k$ and
>   $\lim_{k \to \infty}\phi(x,k)=f(x)$. This means that $f$ can be computably approximated
>   from above.

Further, using the squeeze theorem, we could conclude:

> If a function $f$ is both upper semicomputable and lower semicomputable
>   on its domain, then we call $f$ **computable**

Comment: Thanks, relating the term to **upper semicomputable** helps a lot! Also I believe the function $H$ is related to the Kolmogorov complexity , although the prof hasn't used that term.